# Is it possible to have multiple types with the same variable name?

Tags: java

first time using this to make questions but I hope I'll get an answer.

So my problem is, I'm making a program, that connects to a Robot (in this case a Robot Lego (EV3 or NXT)). Each robot has is own class to start, EV3 have "xxxEV3" and the NXT "xxxNXT". Because I don't have always acess to the physical robot I made a new class (that i called myRobot) that has the same methods that the other two classes, so far i was using the same "variable" (same name) to test, but whenever I change the physical robot i had to comment the line so there wouldn't be any problem.

Example:

```
class gui extends.... {
   //private myRobot robot;
   //private xxxEV3 robot;
   private xxxNXT robot;
   public gui() {
      //robot = new myRobot();
      //robot = new xxxEV3();
      robot = new xxxNXT();
   ...
   }
   public void move(int dist) {
       robot.move(dist);
   }
}
```

So as you can see, every time i change the "type" of robot i was using i had to comment so there wouldn't be any errors.

So now I want to make a drop-down on my GUI that if I choose myRobot it starts my myRobot class using the same name as above (robot) or if I choose EV3 it starts my xxxEV3 class using robot as the name of the variable ...

I hope I made myself clear enough to get an answer, because I really can't get that myself.

Comment: look into interfaces if you want to achieve this type of behavior

Comment: And inheritance with  a polymorphic behavior

Comment: As an aside: the code you show doesn't follow normal Java naming conventions. This isn't *wrong*, exactly, but it's probably worthwhile for you to learn how things in Java are named (and, in particular, capitalized). This will make your code more "natural" in the language, and will also make it easier for others to read and understand your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible due to confusion when setting the type. But a way to do this would be to use inheritance and extending myRobot, EV3, xxxEV3, etc. from a base Robot interface.

```
public interface Robot {
    public void move(int distance);
}

public class myRobot implements Robot {
    public void move(int distance) {
        // implementation here
    }
}
```